# Using ScanSnap S510M on macOS Catalina

Tags: mac, scanner, macos-catalina

I have an old Fujitsu ScanSnap S510M scanner that works perfectly well from a hardware perspective.  However, as of my upgrade to macOS Catalina, the software no longer works, which effectively bricks it.  Per [Fujitsu's support page on the question](https://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/products/computing/peripheral/scanners/scansnap/faq/s510-catalina.html):

> The ScanSnap software (*) is not available on macOS 10.15 Catalina. To
> keep using your ScanSnap, use it on the current version of macOS. When
> you update your macOS, please consider purchasing a ScanSnap that is
> currently available.
>
> Details
>
> The ScanSnap software (*) is not available on the macOS as it does not support any 32-bit applications.（No further updates will be provided to the ScanSnap software.）
>
> If you will use macOS 10.13 or earlier, you can keep using ScanSnap
> S510M on the OS. When you use macOS 10.14 or later, please consider
> purchasing a ScanSnap that is currently available.
>
> (*) e.g. ScanSnap Manager

Is there any way to keep using ScanSnap Manager S510M in macOS Catalina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250714540) on Apple's discussion forums:

> Hamrick Software, maker of VueScan scanning software, supports the S510M as well as too many others to count.

You can download VueScan [here](https://www.hamrick.com/download.html).  It's got a free version that puts a watermark on scans and a paid version that doesn't.  The watermark-free paid versions cost $40-$80, although at those prices it isn't all that much more to just buy a new scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that worked for me - I installed MacOS Lion in Parallels (running on my Macbook Pro Catalina) and was able to get back to the same functionality from the original supported Scansnap software from Fujitsu.

Note: I tried a lot of different versions of MacOS and Lion was the only one that worked without issue. YMMV with other versions of MacOS.